# How to override wishlist sidebar file in my own module?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, wishlist, phtml

I want to override sidebar.phtml file of wishlist module in my own module.

Please guide me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you want to change `sidebar.phtml`.

### Create New Layout file at Custom Module:

for this case.You need to create a frontend layout file `customwishlist.xml` from this custom module like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <!-- start of routers 
    -->
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custommodule>
                    <file>customwishlist.xml</file>
                </custommodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

### Change template file at new layout file

then on `customwishlist.xml` file using `siderbar.phtml` name  and using `setTemplate` function set template .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->
    <default> <!--  wishlist_sidebar sidebar block name define at wishlist.xml -->
        <reference name="wishlist_sidebar">
              <action method="setTemplate"><template>youpath/customsider.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </default></layout>
```

Comment: You are welcome..;)

Comment: Hi amit, is it possible, to get wishlist sidebar section and put in to my custom phtml, can you pls guide me this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/333565/57334  thanks.