# Proper way to get $block->getChildHtml inside the custom phtml file

Tags: blocks, magento2.4.1

I want to add default [wishlist sidebar section](https://snipboard.io/qgLr7a.jpg) into my Magento_Theme template,

Layout xml file:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.panel">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mylocation.block" template="Magento_Theme::location_link.phtml" after="-">

              <!-- Wishlist sidebar section -->
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::sidebar.phtml"/> 

            </block>

        </referenceBlock>
```

FYI : The following code coming from core **vendor\magento\module-wishlist\view\frontend\templates\sidebar.phtml**

```
  <!-- Wishlist sidebar section -->
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::sidebar.phtml"/>
```

After added in layout xml file and getting this block using getChildHtml in app\desigh\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Theme\templates\location_link.phtml

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('wishlist');?>
```

Not working, any help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is not working because your blocks are siblings and do not have a parent/child relationship. The key is the word `child` in `getChildHtml`.

If you nest your wishlist block inside the location block that will work.

Also, `header.panel` is a container, not a block. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/5e57ddd6b0452121e26ce93c74029cf58c4b1d6b/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml#L34

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mylocation.block" template="Magento_Theme::location_link.phtml" after="-">
            <!-- Wishlist sidebar section -->
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="wishlistc" template="Magento_Wishlist::sidebar.phtml"/> 
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: After i updated your code, still response not return to the phtml file, i am trying to get the wishlist sidebar section in my phtml file? 

Screenshot : https://snipboard.io/qgLr7a.jpg

Comment: In my phtml file i am using : <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('wishlistc');?>

Comment: That's correct. Is your `location_link.phtml` file rendering on the frontend?

Comment: Yes, but still wishlist sidebar not showing.

Comment: code: https://codeshare.io/5QxPpL

Comment: On that code your block has a different name. On Stack Exchange it has an alias of `wishlistc` but on codeshare it has an alias of `wishlist`. Have you tried making sure the alias matches the argument to getChildHtml?

Comment: "wishlist" is the correct name, i am changed, still not working

Comment: I am updated my post, can i get any help regarding this issue?

Comment: I have just updated my answer, can you try again please? I noticed that you were using referenceBlock when it should be referenceContainer

Comment: How to do customization this section, should i copy the files from the module-wishlist put into my theme like Magento_Wishlist, then only i can able to customize it right? I need the best approach to do

Comment: Do not copy the files, you should create a new file with the same name within your theme. You want to extend the core not copy/paste it (unless it's a template)

Answer (score 0):

Try to move it instead:

```
   <move element="wishlist_sidebar" destination="mylocation.block" before="-"/>
```

Also make sure to clear the cache, sometimes not even when running flush and clear cache, magento stop using cached. When it happens I need to clear static files.
I recommend disable **full_page** and **block_html** cache while you working on it:

```
bin/magento c:d full_page

bin/magento c:d block_html
```

Comment: FYI - I try to get that wishlist section inside the dropdown dialog widget https://bit.ly/3vZtpPe, i have icon on header if customer click that icon dropdown show the wishlist products,  so that i am using <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('wishlist');?>
 inside the phtml file.